# Jquery Datatable default sorting not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table containing 3 columns A, B and C. Now By default I want to sort it on base of C at start. But I don't know why It's not working. It's shows the down arrow on columns C, but data are not sorted.

[image]

```
{
  "processing": true,
  "scrollX": true,
  "columns": [
    {
        bSortable: true
        bVisible: true
        data: "A"
        filtering: true
        label: "A"
        mData: "A"
        mRender: (data, type, row)
        orderable: true
        render: (data, type, row)
        total: false
        visible: true
    },
    {
        bSortable: true
        bVisible: true
        data: "B"
        filtering: true
        label: "B"
        mData: "B"
        mRender: (data, type, row)
        orderable: true
        render: (data, type, row)
        total: false
        visible: true
    },
     {
        bSortable: true
        bVisible: true
        data: "C"
        filtering: true
        label: "C"
        mData: "C"
        mRender: (data, type, row)
        orderable: true
        render: (data, type, row)
        total: false
        visible: true
    },
  ],
  "pageLength": 10,
  "paging": true,
  "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
  "lengthChange": false,
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bDeferRender": true,
  "bSortable": true,
  "columnDefs": [],
  "searching": false,
  "oScroll": {
    "iBarWidth": 7
  },
  "dom": "frtlS",
  "aaSorting": [ [ 2, "desc" ] ],
  "aoColumnDefs": [
    {
      "aTargets": [ 0 ], "bSortable": true
    },
    {
      "aTargets": [ 1 ], "bSortable": true
    },
    {
      "aTargets": [ 2 ], "bSortable": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Any type of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see some of the data?

Comment: @psalmody : I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Try removing all periods from those numbers in the data and see if it sorts then. I bet it's a sorting issue with the number format you have. Do columns A & B sort OK?

Comment: When I manually sort column C after the table loads completely, It works. It sorts correct. So I don't think period is an issue here.

Comment: Your code seems to be broken - missing commas, no function definitions for `render` and `mRender`. Are you sure this is the code you're using? Can you create an example on [jsFiddle](https://jsFiddle.net)?